# jquery.validate is disallowing new lines in text areas

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET application, I inherited from an old development team. They are having an issue where if you type the enter key into an `asp:textbox`, it is ignored instead of the newline being shown. A standard `multiline textbox` is being used here. If I comment out the script declaration for `jquery.validate-1.11.0.js`, the enter key now works as expected.

I am wondering what logic could this script possibly be doing that it would disallow new lines in all text areas on the site like this? I have looked for handling of `keydown` or `keyup` event and cannot find any reference to `textarea` handling of these events in the code. I'm wondering if anyone has maybe seen this before.

Comment: What validation classes/rules are being applied to the textarea?

Comment: @nFreeze that's just the thing: I have literally declare only a standard <asp:textbox> with no html validators in it. I don't understand how this could happen (it is sitting in a form which is being validated, but contains no validators on this specific textbox)

Comment: I am unable to reproduce on my system. Could you post your code?